# What is a MemoryView in the .NET browser-wasm runtime?

Tags: javascript, .net, webassembly, jsimport, browser-wasm

In the new (non-Blazor) `browser-wasm` runtime of .NET 7 there are `JSImport` attributes for communicating with Javascript imports. [Many .NET types are supported for passing as arguments to Javascript functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-interop-on-).

If you pass a `Span<>` or `ArraySegment<>` then you must marshal them as a `MemoryView`, but I can't see any documentation for what that actually is. What does the JS function actually receive? Is it a wrapper for a typed array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not documented, we can see the implementation of `MemoryView` here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8cb3bf89e4b28b66bf3b4e2957fd015bf925a787/src/mono/wasm/runtime/marshal.ts#L379

It has the functions

- byteLength
- copyTo
- length
- set
- slice
- _unsafe_create_view

`set` and `slice` behave like the TypedArray functions (in particular, `slice` makes a new buffer.) `_unsafe_create_view` looks like an internal function, but it is exposed, and would let you get the TypedArray directly, which would be slightly more efficient.